# Como pegar o valor dinamicamente de um select

Tags: php, html-select

Olá pessoal alguém pode da uma força nesse probleminha que travei? Já que não sou muito bom em javascript.
To querendo pegar o valor de um select dinamicamente e de acordo com o select selecionado fazer um pesquisa dinâmica SQL em projeto feito em php puro.

```
echo '<select name="op">';
echo  '<option value="Rede">Rede</option>';
echo   '<option value="Suport">Suporte</option>';
echo   '<option value="Backend">BackEnd</option>';
echo   '<option value="FrontEnd">FrontEnd</option>';
echo '</select>';

$qq = $_POST['op'];
$q3 = "SELECT * FROM `lcm_author` WHERE `sector` LIKE '$qq'";
$query3 = lcm_query($q3);
```

Comment: Você pode usar AJAX para isso... utilize o evento `$("select").change(function(){});` do select e dispare uma chamada AJAX para buscar os dados dinamicamente. Isso com JQuery, só pra constar. Se você já tiver alguma coisa do javascript, poste junto na pergunta para vermos.

Comment: Na verdade não tenho nada em javascript para essa funcionalidade, a grande questão é que não sei fazer isso ! Tentei pegar o exemplo que tem na internet sobre (pesquisa estado/cidade dinamicamente) para ter uma base, mas mesmo assim não consigo fazer as alterações certa.

Comment: Da uma pesquisada em AJAX (requisição assíncrona) e JQuery, com isso você consegue resolver sua questão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arquivo JS

```
$("select").change(function(){ //Evento quando o elemento select é alterado.
    $.ajax({
        url: "filtrar.php", //Página que fará a busca no banco de dados
        type: 'POST',
        data: { filtro: $(this).val() }, //Variáveis postadas para o arquivo definido
        complete: function (e, xhr, result){
            if(e.readyState ==4 && e.status ==200){
                try{
                    var Obj = eval("("+ e.responseText + ")");//combo os
                }
                catch(err){
                }
                if(Obj != null){
                    if(Obj.msg == '1'){
                        console.log(Obj);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Nenhum registro retornado');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Arquivo PHP

```
    $setor = $_POST['filtro'];

    $retorno = array();

    $sql = "SELECT ... WHERE sector LIKE (:filtro);";

    $vars = array(":filtro"=>"%{$setor}%");

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    foreach($vars as $index => $value){
        $stmt->bindValue($index,$value);
    }

    if($stmt->execute()){
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $rows['msg'] = '1';
        $rows['length'] = $count;

        $i = 0;
        while($i < $count){
            foreach($rows[$i] as $index => $value){
                $rows[$i]->$index = ($value);
            }
            $i++;
        }

        return json_encode($rows,true);
    } else {
        return json_encode(array("msg" => '0'),true);
    }
```

Adriano, use de base e tente elaborar alguma coisa por conta para você começar a entender a manipular os eventos por javascript.

Esse arquivo PHP de exemplo esta utilizando PDO, se precisar adapte ao que você esta acostumado. O retorno dessa rotina é um JSON com todos os registros recuperados do banco. Dê uma pesquisada se não conhece sobre o JSON.

Não esqueça de incluir a biblioteca JQuery no seu cabeçalho do código, se não nada disso funcionará

JQuery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: você tirou minha trava!
Nessa funcionalidade **"url"** do ajax eu posso colocar a próprio caminho do arquivo(chamando ele mesmo)? Já que tudo vai ficar em um único arquivo! Ou vou ter que separar mesmo ?

Comment: Pra vc usar a mesma página pra tudo, vc vai ter q colocar alguns IFs pra quando a requisição AJAX for chamada, apenas a impressão dos dados recuperados do banco podem aparecer, que seria `echo json_encode()`. Mas eu recomendo que vc tenha um arquivo com o HTML outro com JS e outro com a pesquisa no banco, assim fica muito mais organizado e vc não precisa ficar fazendo IFs desnecessários para rodar apenas um pedaço do código quando o AJAX for chamado.

Answer (score 1):

**Muto bem então a pergunta que temos é:**
Como pegar valores do select pelo servidor PHP sem fazer "refresh" na página?
**A resposta é:**
Use AJAX, existem algumas formas de se usar Ajax e na minha opinião a mais fácil e compatível é com jQuery.

Imagine que tenhamos uma página de login/cadastro e queremos que ela envie as informações para o servidor mais sem sair dela em hipótese alguma, esse seria um exemplo semelhamente ao seu.

É muito simples, basicamente precisamos de 2 arquivos index.html e cadastro.php

código completo: [download código completo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBEh4QJvkXjandhRFFJRWlwY2M/view?usp=sharing)

**index.html** é simplesmente um arquivo HTML com o formulário comum que já conhecemos a diferença está na função **ajax**

```
var campos = {nome: "Joao", idade: 32};
$.ajax({
            data: campos,// dados que serão enviados para o servidor
            url: "cadastro.php", // url a buscar sem fazer refresh (ajax)
            type: "POST", // método de envio dos dados (GET,POST)
            dataType: "html", // como será recebida a resposta do servidor (html,json)
            success: function(data){ // função que tras a resposta quando tudo der certo
               alert(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("problema ao carregar a solicitação");
            }
        });
```

**campos** é a variável com os dados a serem enviados, **success** é a função que é chamada quando tudo terminar, type  é o modo de envio dos dados que também pode ser GET

**cadastro.php**
Você simplesmente pega os campos, faz o que quiser com eles e imprime uma resposta

```
<?php
echo "você enviou os campos: <br/>";
print_r($_POST);
```

Mais detalhes em:

[jquery.com](http://jquery.com)

[função ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: No meu form "<form action="pop_up_upd.php" method="post">" tem vários select dentro dele esse é um deles, o form chama um outro arquivo php que tem a select do banco.

Comment: então em teoria estaria certo, já tentou dar um echo na variável $qq pra ver se o valor está vindo?, acho que o problema pode ser o seu SQL tente alterar o valor de $q3 para
$q3 = "SELECT * FROM `lcm_author` WHERE `sector` LIKE '%$qq%'";

Outra dica é que pegue essa query faça um 'echo' e depois rode no banco pra ver se funciona

Comment: O grande problema é que tem que na hora que se mudar a opção do select.Essa é a grande questão.

Comment: @deFreitas , acredito que o problema do Adriano não é o funcionamento do filtro. Mas ele quer tornar o filtro dinâmico, sem reloads. Então ele tem que usar AJAX para alterar o conteúdo da página dinamicamente quando um novo valor é selecionado no `SELECT`. É isso Adriano?

Comment: Isso mesmo! @DanielRibeiro

Comment: Bom acho que entendi @AdrianoCarvalho de uma olhada na resposta que reformulei e veja se resolve seu problema