# Criar combo com nomes dentro do value do input

Tags: php, html, mysql

tenho o input com o name colaborador dentro do while:

```
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['nome'].'</td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" name= "Colaborador" value=""</td>';
```

Dentro do `value` pretendo fazer uma consulta à tabela dos colaboradores e criar uma combo com os nomes dos colaboradores todos, para assim eles só terem de selecionar o seu nome em vez de escrever.

Dentro do `value` pretendia fazer tipo isto que fiz no `select`:

```
<label for=""><h5><strong>Colaborador</strong></h5></label>
<select name="Colaborador" required>
       <option></option>
        <?php
         $servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8'); 

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.colaboradores WHERE descricaovalencia = 'lar' AND estado = 1 AND Funcao = 'AAD' ORDER BY nome ASC";
         $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
            echo '<option value="'.$ln['nome'].'">'.$ln['nome'].'</option>';
         }
      ?>        
    </select>
```

**Resolvi o problema desta forma:**

```
<td WIDTH="80" align="center"> <select name="Colaborador" id="Colaborador">
   <option></option>
<option value="1">teste</option>
</select></td>';
```

Em vez de Utilizar um `input` utilizei o `select`.

Comment: Cara, não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, pode ser um pouco mais claro?

Comment: Você quer usar o campor $rows_corsos['nome'] pra fazer uma nova consulta?

Comment: Já editei a perguntei e mostrei o que queria fazer dentro do `value`, tipo o que faço dentro do `select`

Comment: O que você esta querendo não é possivel, você simples pode substituir seu input text pelo input select, o que facilitaria seria queria seu input select numa variavel antes de montar a tabela, depois no lugar no input text voce utilizar o echo sua variavel.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aí

Comment: @marcelogribeiro, pode colocar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

tambem não entendi o que você pretente fazer.
Mas ja pensou em usar Jquery ou JavaScript para essa ação?

Tipo, ao selecionar a option do select ele dispara um evento para preencher o input

Se for isso é bem simples de fazer.

```
<select name="produto" id="Produto"  onchange="javascript:associaInput();"*>


function associaInput() {
    //pega o value do select
    var e = document.getElementById("Produto");
    var itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    //injeta no value do input
    document.getElementByName('produto.Produto').value = itemSelecionado;
}
```

Comment: Seria isso??? se não for, seja um pouco mais especifico

Comment: Dentro do input eu quero fazer uma consulta à tabela da base de dados para aparecerem logo todos os nomes que existem dentro da tabela, Assim o utilizador não precisa de estar a escrever o seu nome

Comment: Use o input com autocomplete . Conforme ele for digitando o nome dele vai aparecendo na busca. Tipo o Google. Você escre e ele vai sugerindo.

Comment: conhece Jquery? é bem simples de implementar. Vai fazer chamada ao evento a cada letra que for digitada. Daí ele retorna a lista da tua query. Da uma pesquisada em uns exemplos. qualquer coisa posta ai que te ajudo.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
<label for=""><h5><strong>Colaborador</strong></h5></label>
<select name="Colaborador" required>
   <option></option>

    <?php

    $servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
    $username = "xxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxx";
    $dbname = "xxxxxx";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if($th = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM centrodb.colaboradores WHERE descricaovalencia = 'lar' AND estado = 1 AND Funcao = 'AAD' ORDER BY nome ASC");
   whiel($row = $th->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<option value="'.$row['nome'].'">'.$row['nome'].'</option>';

   }

  ?>        
</select>
```

Comment: E depois como chamo este select dentro do value do input?

Comment: @Iniciante dá uma olhada nisso aí: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44174/como-pegar-o-valor-dinamicamente-de-um-select